# how to use iap windows phone 8 remove ads?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, in-app-purchase

I'm trying to add an IAP to remove ads in my apps, but I can't find a good clear tutorial on how to do it.
I tried the next ones:
http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/wpapps/Free-App-With-Paid-Products-f138d4a8

But that one is just the code without any explanation.

I also tried and followed every step of this one:
http://www.visuallylocated.com/post/2013/07/19/Remove-ads-with-an-in-app-purchase-across-your-entire-app.aspx

My ad is inside a UserControl, since I use multiple pages and just call the UserControl the next way:
`<Grid Height="auto" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
            <local:Advertisement x:Name="advertisement" Width="480" Height="80" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
        </Grid>`

And the UserControl code:
`

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="{StaticResource PhoneChromeBrush}">
    <Ads:AdControl HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0" Height="70" PublisherID="XXXXX"/>
</Grid>
```

`

Basically what I would like to do is to hide the UserControl if the user buys the app through IAP, but I can't figure out how to do it with those tutorials.

Answer (score 3):

If you created your own user control to wrap the ads, you can subscribe to the Loaded event and check the global "AdsRemoved" property. In the loaded event handler, check if ads have been removed. If they have, collapse the control.

```
public Advertisement()
{
    Loaded += OnLoaded;
}

private void OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs)
{
    if (App.AdsRemoved)
    {
        Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
    }
}
```

If your AdsRemoved property caches the value, you need a way to reset the value when a purchase is made. A quick way is to just add a setter

```
private static bool? _adsRemoved;
private bool AdsRemoved
{
    get
    {
        if (_adsRemoved == null)
        {
            _adsRemoved =  CurrentApp.LicenseInformation.ProductLicenses["RemoveAdsProductID"].IsActive;
        }
        return _adsRemoved.Value;
    }
    set 
    { 
        _adsRemoved =  CurrentApp.LicenseInformation.ProductLicenses["RemoveAdsProductID"].IsActive;
    }
}
```

Then when the purchase is made, call the setter with any value.

```
App.AdsRemoved = true; // or false. Doesn't matter what the value is
```

Following my post, this will not remove the ad from the current page (as it is only removed when the control is loaded). But the ads will be removed from all other pages.

Comment: thanks for your reply, so if I use it that way, I need to add a way that the user can buy the AdsRemoved option right? Like putting that option through the applicationbar.

Comment: If you use the approach in my blog, it will add a menu item for every page

Comment: I followed your post, I created the AdPhoneApplicationPage, installed in my project, and then renamed the next: `public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage` to `public partial class MainPage : AdPhoneApplicationPage` and also: `<phone:PhoneApplicationPage` to `<localControls:AdPhoneApplicationPage` but it gives me an error that it can't find it, I am missing something from your post but I can't figure out what.

Comment: Did you define "localControls" in your xaml? Is the class public? Try rebuilding?

Comment: I did: `xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Funny_Sounds.Controls"` but it says is an undeclared prefix. I only have actually one page with ads in that app, I don't get it either how to do it like the example from Microsoft.